# Why is my TPM bugged? If I enable checks on PCR 8,9,10, it ALWAYS asks for decryption password even if it shouldn't

Tags: linux, tpm, bios, uefi

I've also checked with systemd-analyze pcrs if PCRs are the same at every reboot, and they are.

Only at first reboot I don't know why the only PCRs that change are 8,9,10 lol(I don't know why)... but in next reboots they are always the same, so it shouldn't prompt me the decryption disk password.

Comment: What events does the TCG event log contain within those PCRs? Their values at the time of early boot might not necessarily be the same as after the boot has finished.

Comment: What is your motherboard model? Some don't actually measure BIOS settings, or need that enabled like: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/virtual-edge-platform-4600-8c/bios_user_guide_pub/trusted-computing?guid=guid-0adbd06a-e96c-4d75-8009-64cf3161d9b5&lang=en-us

Comment: @Cpt.Whale motherboard HP 89FC, bios version AMI F.16

Comment: @u1686_grawity what should I check via `sudo tpm2_eventlog /sys/kernel/security/tpm0/binary_bios_measurements` ? I don't have it clear